# Restar dos consultas en PHP MySQL usando phpExcel

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Intento realizar la resta de dos campos que se encuentran en consultas diferentes y que están almacenadas en columnas de un archivo excel creado desde PHP. Y ademas los campos que voy a restar son interactivos, aún no encuetro una forma de lograrlo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Aclara tu pregunta, asi como esta, no se entiende que tenes, que queres y que hiciste hasta ahora

Comment: podrías agregar el codigó amigo